# EmberJs - Linking to multiple dynamic routes, multiple nested levels

Tags: ember.js, link-to, ember-router

To link to record you can use something like this in your route:

```
  this.route('clients', function() {
      this.route('all',function(){
          this.route('view',{
              path:'view/:client_id'
          });
      });
  });
```

So if the user were to go to:
**/clients/all/view/-KdFmDwwWAHDFjjaG6aA**

They could view that client record.

Is it possible to link at a deeper level? For example:

**/clients/all/view/-KdFmDwwWAHDFjjaG6aA/property/-KdFeTqqUIKLFqbaP9aB**

?

That way you could be looking at a specific client record and then launch an overlay for example to show the specifics on a single property that client has for sale?

I'm not sure how to structure the router or the link-to to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly. Here is my answer,

Yes, it's possible to have a deeper level, I will change your route config a bit to :

```
this.route('clients', { path: '/clients' }, function(){

    this.route('view', { path: '/:clients_id' }, function(){

      this.route('property', { path: '/property/:property_id' });
    });
  });
```

So in this case, your `link-to` code in the `HBS` would be

```
{{#link-to 'clients.view.property' clientId}}
  whatever
{{/link-to}}
```

and now file structure is :

```
clients/
|___index.hbs
|___view.hbs
|___view/
    |___propery.hbs
```

Please remember that you need to also modify your route.js for each properly. I assumed you don't have any problems for that.

if you need more help please let me know.

Comment: Not sure if the slash before the url in the path matters, but I got it to work.  Thanks!

Comment: what would be directory structure for routes and why view.hbs cant be as index.hbs within view folder

Comment: @piscript it's only my organization, you can do whatever it makes sense more to you. although Matt wants index.hbs to be a list of clients and view just show clients details probably but like I said you are free to change it as long as it works for you